# Not possible to use the latest ember with pre-compiled templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, gruntjs, grunt-ember-templates

I have just installed the latest ember starter kit. It has:

- Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.5
- Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4
- jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1

I am using `grunt-contrib-handlebars@0.5.9` to pre-compile my templates (this is the latest version available). I do not know what version of handlebars is included in that package, but I get the following error when starting the application:

```
Uncaught Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 1.0.0-rc.4) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (== 1.0.0-rc.3).
```

I have even tried loading another handlebars' runtime (version `1.0.0-rc.3`), but ember is not happy about it:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0.0-rc.4, COMPILER_REVISION expected: 3, got: 2 – Please note: Builds of master may have other COMPILER_REVISION values.
```

So ember needs 1.0.0-rc.4, but there is no grunt precompiler available for this version. Catch-22?

Should I drop pre-compiled templates? Having this break every time I upgrade ember is going to be very annoying ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `emberTemplates` grunt task, from here: https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates since this version has the updated dependencies and is maintained from a member of the ember core team.

As I guess you already know, to use the `grunt-ember-templates` you can define a dependence in your `package.json`

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "grunt-ember-templates": "0.4.7"
  }
  ...
```

and run `npm install`.

Hope it helps

Comment: That did help. My `package.json` was a bit confusing: it was specifying `grunt-contrib-handlebars` *and* `grunt-ember-templates`. The former was apparently not used, and I got confused. `grunt-ember-templates` is the right one, and upgrading the version solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - the same error message. In my case the problem was that I was using an ember library that included some templates compiled by a previous version of `grunt-ember-handlebars` So I got a new version of that library that was compiled by the current version of grunt-ember-handlebars and that solved the problem.